# while loop not working for more than one variable php?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, session-variables

I am trying to make a while loop which retrieves all the relevant data from Mysql database but it doesn't work for more than one variable, the problem I think is with the while loop because I have echoed the sql statement and it retrieved the values of the variables right,   the code is:

```
$wherein = implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);
$sql = "select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID = '$wherein'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<table style='width:100%' border='1' >";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th> Product Name</th>";
echo "<th>Product Price </th>" ;
echo "<th>Quantity </th>" ;
echo "</tr>";

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> $". $row['Price'] . "</td>" ;
    echo "<td> <select>
        <option value= '1'>1</option> 
        <option value= '2'>2</option> 
        <option value= '3'>3</option> 
    </select>
    </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

I have tried many things with the code but the problem still exists, I would really appreciate your help, Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by saying _it works with one variable_? BTW there is a **$** before _$row['price']_

Comment: well, its only working 1 time because your query is only getting 1 row, we suppose databases have single id's who aren't duplicated, if your query is: give me some fields from id = single_id, then the result will be 1 row in case it exists...

Comment: @PavulZavala I echoed the query and it have more than one variable

Comment: @bub I mean whenever there is one variable with the query it retrieves the information from the database but when there are more than one variable in the query it doesn't retrieve any information

Comment: @hossam, I am assuming you are meaning `select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID = '$wherein'` retrieves data, and for example `select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID = '$wherein' and Price = '$something'` does not?

Comment: @Sj03rs the only condition to retrieve the data from the database is the ID, I need to retrieve all the information including the price from the database

Comment: @RyanVincent yes it is an array which includes not only numerical data, it is a varchar which includes numeric and alphabets too, it isnot autoincrement on sql I insert it manually based on the some criteria i set on the database for each individual item.

Comment: @RyanVincent I only implode the content of the $_Session['cart'] which includes only the ids

Comment: No it isnot just numerical it includes alphabets too

Answer (score 1):

The `</table>` statement is inside the while loop. Hence once the table is closed after the first loop the rest of the data might not be showing on the browser (it will still be in your html source code). Try it with moving the `</table>` statement to the last line.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that by imploding the variable you will have multiple IDs then you should use the `IN` statement in the sql.

```
$wherein = implode("','", $_SESSION['cart']);
$sql = "select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID IN ( '$wherein' )";
```

The rendered output can be simplified slightly and the table should be closed after the loop! Not knowing the contents of `$wherein` makes it tricky to answer but I would think the `IN` statement seems to fit the nature of a comma separated value being used in the query better than a direct equals `=`

```
$wherein = implode("','", $_SESSION['cart']);
$sql = "select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID IN ( '$wherein' )";
$result= mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

echo "
    <table style='width:100%' border='1' >
        <tr>
            <th> Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price </th>
            <th>Quantity </th>
        </tr>";

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $result ) ){
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>{$row->Name}</td>
            <td>${$row->Price}</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value= '1'>1
                    <option value= '2'>2
                    <option value= '3'>3
                </select>           
            </td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "
    </table>";


/* Example of using an array of IDs and imploding to generate where conditions for IN clause */

$cart=array('BGL1','BJL');
/* session - cart */

$wherein=implode( "','", $cart );
/* correctly add quotes around each string */

$sql="select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID IN ('$wherein');";
/* use the new $wherein string within quotes */
echo $sql;

>> select ID, Name, Price from lamps WHERE ID IN ('BGL1','BJL');
```

Comment: the first thing I tried on the query was this exact statement but still this problem exists

Comment: what does the final sql look like when the variable has been set? ie: can you show the sql as it is when executed

Comment: When it is executed for more than one variable, it only presents the head of the columns but when there is only one variable it presents all the information of this variable; product name and price

Comment: can you add the final, rendered sql statement? or the contents of `$_SESSION['cart']`?